# ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, es6-modules

I am having a problem with running a nuxt-project on my Windows PC.

**Context:**

- Nuxt Version: **3.0.0-rc.8**
- Browser: **any**
- OS: **Windows 10.0.19045**
- Node: **v18.16.1**
- Terminal: **Git Bash 2.41.0.windows.2**

This works completely fine on Mac, but on Windows I get this error:

```js
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file and data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1059:11)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1135:3)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)
```

To fix this I tried:

- Ran `yarn` to install all modules
- Updating node to the latest recommended version **(v18.16.1)**
- Installing Vue CLI
- Checked for any usage of `c:` (not found)
- Checked for any useage of `normalize(path)` (not found)

I've googled allot and I'm not really sure where to look anymore.

Comment: How did you fix it? I am facing the same problem 

Comment: I didn't sorry. Just continued on mac.